# Changes done is unity web player html not reflected in Facebook canvas app URL

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I developed a small game using unity3d and Facebook unity3d SDK . I am able to do everything from login to post feed or app requests or score.
My only problem is addition of extra html or JQuery scripts done in the Webbuild.html file do not get reflected in Facebook canvas app page.
Facebook only displays my game and all the html or Javascript is simply trimmed off.

I need to fill the blank white space around my Facebook canvas game with my self designed HTML code snippets.
Any suggestions or help is most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

We will be introducing convenient methods to add padding and centering for the unity web player from within Unity (as well as customizable splash screen when loading through the Facebook Settings).

Further customizations can be done through Unity's `ExternalEval` call.

Comment: when can i expect the new release brian ?
And it would be really great if you could help me with sample code snippet to fill the white space left out after loading the facebook canvas app....all I want is custom background image surrounding my facebook game of resolution 760x512 px( width x height).

Comment: Sorry, I missed this comment the first time around, I don't know when the next update will be, but the resolution can be set with `FB.Canvas.SetResolution`

We do have jQuery in the page so you can look into http://jquery.com/ to see how to change the background and the position the div element that holds the player: `$('#unityPlayerEmbed')`